# R programming - date format

Tags: r, excel, csv, ggplot2, time-series

I have an Excel data file with two columns: the first is a column of dates in the format dd-mmm-yy and the second is a column of (jogging) times in minutes. I saved the Excel file as a .CSV file. The name of the file is **RunningD.CSV**.

First, I extracted the data in R with:

```
dataD<- read.csv("RunningD.csv")
```

I then plotted the data in R with the following code:

```
qplot(as.Date(dataD$Date,'%d-%b-%y'), dataD$Time, xlab="Date",
  ylab="Time (mins)", color=dataD$Time)
```

However, the x-axis only shows the month of the dates, not, as desired, the day-month-year.
[See data plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7u9SU.png)

Does anyone know why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use scale_x_datetime if you want to change the default labels

Comment: Here's a reference: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_date.html

Comment: @chinsoon12, I opened the .CSV file in notepad. The data looks like this:
27-Apr-15,22:56
29-Apr-15,22:10
06-May-15,23:34, etc.